# DI issue in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have an odata query builder class that I am using to build my odata string that is desterilising the result based on the object that called it.

```
public class UosOdataQueryBuilder<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _queryOptions;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public UosOdataQueryBuilder([FromServices] IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, [FromServices] ILogger logger)
        {
            _queryOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public UosOdataQueryBuilder<T> WithFilter(string filter)
        {
            _queryOptions.Add("$filter", filter);
            return this;
        }

        public UosOdataQueryBuilder<T> Skip(int skip)
        {
            _queryOptions.Add("$skip", skip.ToString());
            return this;
        }

        public UosOdataQueryBuilder<T> Top(int top)
        {
            _queryOptions.Add("$top", top.ToString());
            return this;
        }

        public UosOdataQueryBuilder<T> WithNoInlineCount()
        {
            _queryOptions.Add("$inlinecount", "none");
            return this;
        }

        public UosOdataQueryBuilder<T> OrderBy(string orderBy)
        {
            _queryOptions.Add("$orderby", orderBy);
            return this;
        }

        public async Task<UosOdataReponse<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync(string elementName = "")
        {
            var result = new UosOdataReponse<T>();

            try
            {
                var authToken = AppSettings.PlatformBearerToken;

                var queryParameters = new List<string>();

                foreach (var option in _queryOptions)
                    queryParameters.Add($"{option.Key}={option.Value}");

                var queryParametersCombined = string.Join("&", queryParameters);

                var oDataElementName = (elementName == "") ? typeof(T).Name : elementName;

                var baseUrl = AppSettings.PlatformBaseUri;
               
                var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("UOS");

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
                    HttpMethod.Get,
                    new Uri(baseUrl + $"/uos/v4/odata/{oDataElementName}" + queryParametersCombined));

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UosOdataReponse<T>>(data);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I have setup the client in startup

```
services.AddHttpClient("UOS", c =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.GetValue<string>("PlatformBaseUri") + "uos/v4/");
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Configuration.GetValue<string>("PlatformBearerToken"));
                //c.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            });
```

When I create a new instance of this from another method it is requiring that I pass in the clientFactory and logger.

```
protected async Task<int> GetUosOdataCount(string filter)
        {
            var result = new List<T>();
            try
            {
                var countCheck = await new UosOdataQueryBuilder<T>()
                    .WithFilter(filter)
                    .Top(1)
                    .ExecuteQueryAsync();

                return countCheck.Count;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //CustomLogger.LogError(GetType().FullName, "GetUosOdata", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

In .NET Framework I would remove the parameters from the constructor of the UosOdataQueryBuilder and resolve the dependencies within it. For Example:

```
_uosUserAttributeRepository = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IUosUserAttributeRepository)) as IUosUserAttributeRepository;
```

But I am not sure how to achieve in .NET Core. Any suggestions?

Comment: just inject what you want in the parent scope (the container class constructor). In this case you have 2 options: inject dependencies of `UosOdataQueryBuilder` including `ILogger` and `IHttpClientFactory`, the second option is injecting the `UosOdataQueryBuilder` directly. Of course that `UosOdataQueryBuilder` should be reigstered. You should take a round with DI in asp.net core first, it is much easier than all frameworks you've worked with before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an interface for `UosOdataQueryBuilder<T>` and register it into `DI` generically. some thing like this:

```
public interface IUosOdataQueryBuilder<T>
{
    Task<T> SomeMethod();
}

public class UosOdataQueryBuilder<T> : IUosOdataQueryBuilder<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _queryOptions;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<UosOdataQueryBuilder<T>> _logger;

    public UosOdataQueryBuilder(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, ILogger<UosOdataQueryBuilder<T>> logger)
    {
        _queryOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task<T> SomeMethod()
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

And in `ConfigureServices` in startup write this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IUosOdataQueryBuilder<>), typeof(UosOdataQueryBuilder<>));
```

And in your controller inject the `IUosOdataQueryBuilder`:

```
    private readonly IUosOdataQueryBuilder<YourClass> _uosOdataQueryBuilder;
    public YourController( IUosOdataQueryBuilder<YourClass> uosOdataQueryBuilder)
    {
       _uosOdataQueryBuilder = uosOdataQueryBuilder;
    }
```

you can register `IUosOdataQueryBuilder` as `Singleton` but for prevent memory leak you should inject `IServiceScopeFactory` in concrete class to get registered service in your methods not in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with comment to stick with injection but you can retrieve the dependencies within the class using [IServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=net-5.0)

e.g

```
MyMethod(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
MyService svc = (MyService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(MyService));
...
```